# Minecraft installation gets stuck downloading Minecraft runtime?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft installation gets stuck downloading the runtime and it does not advance past that point:

[image: Minecraft Updater stuck at 15.70/40.34 MB]

I've tried restarting it over 20 times but it stays stuck. I’ve tried to reinstall it, but it does not work. It seems to get stuck on **15.69**,**15.70** or **15.71** and sometimes **22.52**. Then, after a while it says:

> Unable to start the Minecraft Runtime Enviroment. This is most likely caused by a corruption. Please try to reinstall Minecraft.

But even after I repair it, it still doesn't work. Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Just FYI you can use the 'Snipping Tool' in Windows 7 and up to screenshot only a particular section of the screen. I have cropped the image for you this time :). Unfortunately I'm not sure what's going on with the error itself. Have you tried removing the `.minecraft` folder (save your worlds first!) and starting again? Have you tried downloading a new copy of the installer?

Comment: Yes I have. I did remove .minecraft folder and a new copy of the installer.

Comment: Hmm. How's your internet connection? Do you experience dropouts occasionally? Other than that I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: No in fact I don't. I don't really think its the internet, everything else is fine

Comment: with the installer how big is it? right click on the installer and go to properties to see what it says

Comment: @monkeymanminecraft answer to your onw question with the solution so people coming here for the same issue could have a way of correcting it

Comment: no it really doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this at school/work? Most have internet firewalls that prevent things from downloading, no way past that.
If you're at home, it's likely the installer's malfunctioning. Try going to https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe and download that. Save it instead of immediately running it. You will need Java installed for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug with Avast Antivirus software that messes it up for some reason. You should be able to fix it by disabling the web and file shields while the runtime's downloading and enabling them after. It worked for me, but I'm on mac so it might be different.

Found this out from here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-3959

Comment: That's an OSX bug report. He is using Windows.